# Matplotlib boxplot "fill" is not opaque over violin plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I'm trying to overlay a boxplot over a violin plot, but despite setting the "fill" for the boxes to be white, they're not coming up as completely white because they're not opaque. You can see in the picture below how they're allowing the underlying color to seep through. I've tried toying around with zorder a million times but to no avail. Does anyone know how I can make the white completely opaque? Here's my code, and a picture of the plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 12.5))

vp = ax.violinplot(dataset[:2], widths=0.7, showextrema=False)

list_of_colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange']
for color, poly in zip(list_of_colors, vp['bodies']):
    poly.set_facecolor(color)
    poly.set_edgecolor('#333333')
    poly.set_alpha(0.95)

bp = ax.boxplot(dataset[:2], sym='', widths=0.1, patch_artist=True)

for linetype in bp.values():
    for line in linetype:
        line.set_color('black')
        line.set_alpha(0.5)

for patch in bp['boxes']:
    patch.set(facecolor='white')
```

[image]

Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you try `patch.set(alpha=1)`?

Comment: Holy cow! That worked!! I cannot believe I didn't try that. Wow. Can you add an actual answer so I can award you? (By the way, why would the alpha not be 1 by default?) Thank you so so much!

Comment: You changed the alpha in `for linetype in bp.values(): for line in linetype: line.set_alpha(0.5)`.  It is a bit confusing that you call all `bp.values()` a linetype while there are also rectangles (due to `patch_artist=True`), but is certainly makes sense to set the line properties of the rectangle edges similar to the other lines.  Note that you can also set properties via ` ax.boxplot(...., boxprops={'facecolor': 'white'})`

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be very useful for other people, as someone with a similar problem is extremely unlikely to encounter this question. It would make sense to close it.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for your help, really appreciate it.